# Issue setting up Velostrata target cloud extension

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-migrate-for-compute-engine

I'm working with the Velostrata Cloud Manager web UI, trying to set up the target cloud environment (GCP).

Selecting my GCP regions from the Network settings options results in 400 bad request error.

The failing GET request looks like this:

https://[velostrata_manager_host]/velostrata/api/v45/cloud/gcp/networks?projectId=solasta-infra&regionName=us-west1&term=-1

The response is a 400 error:

```
{
  "errorCode" : "BadRequestInvalidArgument",
  "url" : "https://[velostrata_manager_host]/velostrata/api/v45/cloud/gcp/networks",
  "message" : "Project id cant be empty"
}
```

The projectId parameter is not empty as you can see from the GET request.

Comment: Generally the project id is referenced on GCP APIs as `project`, not `projectId`

Comment: @manasouza I don't have control over the parameter name. This is the request the Velostrata web UI sends. Possible a bug in the Velostrata API.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account which you are created for Velostrata have the correct Project ID. The night be because of you have created Velostrata role at the project level not organizational level.

For instance if your goal is to migrate the VMs to multiple projects, then we need to create Velostrata at the organizational level not project level.